# shopping cart oscommerce

Tags: php, shopping-cart, oscommerce

I want to retrieve `products_tax_class_ids` in checkout payment page in OSCommerce shopping cart software. E.g., the user has 20 items in his shopping cart and if any of product has `products_tax_class_id = 30`, the site will warn him.

This code is not working.

```
$tax = tep_db_query("select products_tax_class_id 
                    from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " 
                    where products_id = '".$card[$products_id]."'");

while ($warn = tep_db_fetch_array($tax)) {
    if (warn== '30') { 
        echo "attention ....";
    } 
    else { 
        echo "..."
    }
}
```

How can I `compare tax_class_id` of products?

Comment: do you see some errors? There are obvious syntax errors in your code

Comment: no, i check error.php, no error, i think i can not select shoppi

Comment: no, i check error.php, no syntax error, i made a class and called in checkout_payment with require, nothing happened. functions like (echo $cart->show_total()) can be called and executed perfectly in checkout payment. $card[$products_id] could be wrong? i tried  contents[$products_id]['products_tax_class_id'] or $orders_products['products_id'] from orders.php in order to products_id = '".$card[$products_id]."'") no results again. i can not understand how i can call items from shopping card and their products_tax_class_ id. little bit confused.

Comment: are you sure `$card` array exists? it could be `$cart` in a shopping cart software

Comment: if i copy and paste shopping card php, would it be problem for forum?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't point name of field in while loop.

```
$tax = tep_db_query("select products_tax_class_id 
                    from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " 
                    where products_id = '".$card[$products_id]."'");

while ($warn = tep_db_fetch_array($tax)) {
    if ($warn['products_tax_class_id'] == '30') { 
        echo "attention ....";
    } 
    else { 
        echo "..."
    }
}
```

And word "card" should be a "cart" I think...

Answer (score 0):

```
/**************************************************************************/
//Add following function in includes/functions/general.php
/**************************************************************************/

function tep_get_products_tax($product_id) {
    global $languages_id;

    if (empty($language)) $language = $languages_id;

    $product_query = tep_db_query("select products_tax_class_id from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " where products_id = '".$product_id."'");
    $product = tep_db_fetch_array($product_query);

    return $product['products_tax_class_id'];
  }


/**************************************************************************/
//Add following code in checkout_payment.php
/**************************************************************************/
$products = $cart->get_products();
for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products); $i<$n; $i++) {
  if (tep_get_products_tax($products[$i]['id']) == 30) {
    echo "attention ....";
break
  }
}
/**************************************************************************/
//EOD
/**************************************************************************/
```